# SSL certificate issue while executing FQL

Tags: php, ssl, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I am trying to execute the following FQL statement:

```
SELECT first_name FROM user WHERE uid = '[logged in user's uid]'
```

Here is my PHP code:

```
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
    'appId' => [my appId],
    'secret' => [my secret]
));

$query = "SELECT first_name FROM user WHERE uid = '$uid'";
$data = $facebook->api(array('method' => 'fql.query', 'query' => $query));
```

I am getting the following error:

```
Exception: SSL certificate problem, verify that the CA cert is OK.
Details: error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:
certificate verify failed
```

I am using the latest Facebook PHP API, and the file fb_ca_chain_bundle.crt is present in the same directory as facebook.php and base_facebook.php.  I am running this on WAMP (Windows, Apache, MySQL and PHP).

I would greatly appreciate your help.

Thank you,

fbwb

Comment: We were getting SSL errors this morning with Facebook.

Comment: This error still occurs.  I would appreciate any helpful responses.

Answer (score 0):

Export the certificate from your browser and import it in your JVM truststore (to establish a chain of trust):

```
<JAVA_HOME>\bin\keytool -import -v -trustcacerts
-alias server-alias -file server.cer
-keystore cacerts.jks -keypass changeit
-storepass changeit
```